# Find the height of statue.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Standing on one side of a 10 meter wide straight road, a man finds that the angle of elevation of a statue located on the same side of the road is X. After crossing the road by the shortest possible distance, the angle reduces to Y. Find the height of statue.

How do we solve this question applying trigonometry?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you draw a picture illustrating the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting the height of the tower be $h$, and the initial distance to the tower be $D$ we arrive initially at the equation:

$tanX = \frac{h}{D}$

After crossing the road, the equation becomes,

$tanY = \frac{h}{\sqrt{D^2 + 10^2}}$

Equating the two yields,

$DtanX = \sqrt{D^2 + 10^2}tanY$

Thus,

$D^2tan^2X = D^2tan^2Y + 100tan^2Y$

Thus,

$D = \sqrt{\frac{100tan^2Y}{tan^2X - tan^2Y}}$

Now we have $D$ we can substitute back into the initial equation to find $h$ as,

$h = tanX\sqrt{\frac{100tan^2Y}{tan^2X - tan^2Y}}$

Comment: I suppose that we do not take into account (or we neglect) the height of the observer. Is it correct ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, yes my assumption was that the height of the observer was insignificant compared to the height of the tower, however without knowing the angles X and Y the validity of this assumption is still in the dark.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! You are right : the problem would be much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Let the height of the flagpole be $h$.

Before you cross the road, the distance along the ground to the base of the flagpole is

\begin{align}
d_1 = \frac{h}{\tan(X)} = h \cot(X)
\end{align}

You cross the road, and now the distance along the ground between you and the base of the flagpole is:

\begin{align}
d_2 = \frac{h}{\tan(Y)} = h \cot(Y)
\end{align}

But now consider the right-angled triangle between your start and end position and the base of the flagpole. It has hypotenuse $d_2$, and two sides of 10m and $d_1$. So, applying pythagoras,

\begin{align}
h^2 \cot^2(Y) &= h^2 \cot^2(X) + (10m)^2 \\
h &= \sqrt{\frac{100}{\cot^2(Y) - \cot^2(X)}} \quad m
\end{align}

Comment: I suppose that we do not take into account (or we neglect) the height of the observer. Is it correct ?

Comment: Indeed. As this information is not available, it cannot be used. (The above calculation determines the height of the flagpole above the height of the observer.) But you're right to point this out!

Comment: Thank you for precising ! Cheers :-)